# Finding out what numbers have been added to come up with a sum

Tags: php, sql, math

Sorry for the title. I wasn't sure how to ask this question.

I have a form on a website that asks a question. The answers are in check box form. Each answer is saved into my database with a 'score', the values look like this:

```
Allergy 1
Cardiology  2
Chest Disease   4
Dermatology 8
Emergency Room  16
Ambulance Trips 32
Gastroenterology    64
General Medicine    128
Gynecology  256
Hematology  512
Neurology   1024
Obstetrics  2048
Opthamology 4096
Orthopedics 8192
Physical Therapy    16384
Plastic Surgery 32768
Podiatry    65536
Proctology  131072
Psychiatry  262144
Surgery Performed   524288
Thoracic Surgery    1048576
Urology 2097152
Outside X-Rays  4194304
Diagnostic Tests (outside)  8388608
```

As you can see, the score is the previous value times two.  When a user fills out the form, the answer is saved in the database as one value - all the answers added together.

For example, a user selected the values: Allergy, General Medicine, Hematology, Obstetrics. In the database, the answer for this question is saved as `2689`.

Is there a way to figure out what answers have been selected by only having the answer to the question?

For example, I would query my database and pull the `2689` value, and I need to determine what answers were checked.

edit: I was hoping to reverse engineer the answer in PHP.

Comment: You would [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) the value with one of the predefined values (using a bitwise `AND`). It depends on your language of use (SQL?) how this would be done.

Comment: If it's an open question (no specific programming language, no point in your program where you're stuck), you're better off asking this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Evert, I've edited my question/tags adding the language I'd like to solve them problem in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the values by ANDing with powers of 2.

2<sup>0</sup> = 1
2<sup>1</sup> = 2
2<sup>2</sup> = 4
2<sup>3</sup> = 8
...
2<sup>23</sup> = 8388608

You can find out the value of 2<sup>n</sup> using binary shifting like this: 1 << n

php like code:

```
$item[] = {"Allergy", "Cardiology", ..., "Diagnostic Tests (outside)"};
$answer = 2689;

for ( $power = 0; $power < count($item); $power++ ) {

   if ( 1 << $power & $answer ) {
       echo $item[$power] . "\n";
   }
}
```

Edit: made it more php friendly

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is a common pattern called [bit masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29). Use your language's binary AND operator on the value corresponding to a given answer and the value submitted from the form to see if the given answer was one of the selected choices. For example, if the answer submitted and saved is `2689` as in your example, you can check whether "chest disease" was one of the selected choices by seeing if `2689 & 4` is nonzero. (`&` should be substituted with whatever the binary AND operator is in your language of choice.)

Note that this only works as long as all the values corresponding to individual choices are powers of 2. In general, the question posed in your title, about finding out what numbers from a given set have been added to come up with a given sum, is an instance of something called the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and is only known to be solvable by checking every possible combination, which is *very* inefficient. (NP-complete, specifically)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Note that each *k*'th "score" is of the form 2^(*k* - 1), which corresponds to a bitstring with only the *k*'th bit set. If you know which bits are set, you can reconstruct the sum.

Taking 2689 as an example, we first need to write it out in binary:

```
2689 = 101010000001b
```

Counting from the right, we see that the first, eighth, tenth and twelfth bits are set, so (as you can verify)

```
2689 = 2^0 + 2^7 + 2^9 + 2^11
     = 1 + 128 + 512 + 2048
```

The actual implementation of this can be done efficiently using bitwise operations. By taking the `AND` of the value and each of the "scores" in turn, then checking whether that gives a non-zero value, we can check which scores went into the sum.

Comment: @etm124: I'm sorry, I don't PHP.

Answer (score 1):

this will do exactly what you wanted :

```
<?php
Print bindecValues("2689");

function bindecValues($decimal, $reverse=false, $inverse=false) {

$bin = decbin($decimal);
if ($inverse) {
    $bin = str_replace("0", "x", $bin);
    $bin = str_replace("1", "0", $bin);
    $bin = str_replace("x", "1", $bin);
}
$total = strlen($bin);

$stock = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    if ($bin{$i} != 0) {
        $bin_2 = str_pad($bin{$i}, $total - $i, 0);
        array_push($stock, bindec($bin_2));
    }
}

$reverse ? rsort($stock):sort($stock);
return implode(", ", $stock);
}
?>
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Remember that integers are stored in binary - so each of these flags (Allergy = 1) etc. will correspond to a single bit being true or false in the binary representation of the sum.

For example, 2689 in binary is `0000 1010 1000 0001` which, if you think of it as an array of bits, where the least significant bit (right most in that array) is the least significant flag (allergy) then we can easily see that the first (allergy), eighth (gen. medicine), tenth (hematology) and twelfth (obs) slots of the array are marked with a 1 for true.

The largest value in your array of flags is 24th bit in a 32 bit integer. You could define up to 8 more flags in this system before having to use a larger integer.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your numbers seem to be powers of two, you just need to store the input value in a long enough integer to hold it, then bit mask.

```
if( value & 1 ) then 1 was part of the selection
if( value & 2 ) then 2 was part of the selection
if( value & 3 ) then 3 was part of the selection
and so on
```